# Location not working for files but only for path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config, nginx-log

I have a nginx.conf that looks like this:

```
server {
  ...
  root /var/opt/data/web;
  ...

  location ~* \.(?:eot|woff|woff2|ttf|js)$ {
    expires 1M;
  }

  ...

  location /one {
    root /var/opt/data/alternatives;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location /two {
    root /var/opt/data/alternatives;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

when I `curl http://localhost/one/` I get the content of `index.html` stored in `/other`. But when I curl `.../localhost/one/foo.js` the file is not found and I get this in the error.log:

> open() "/default/foo.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)

I tried other variants like `location ~ (one|two)`, `location /one/` or even `location ~ /(one|two)` but all of them didn't work.

The complete config consists of a lot more `location`s, but I guess the cause of my problem is the location where I set up `.js` resources to `expire -1` because this prevents changing the root to what I need.

If this matters: I use nginx 1.15.2. In case you are wondering why I have this strange `alternatives` directory: the `web` directory is created by a CMS software while `alternatives` is `git pull`ed.

Comment: Your `try_files` statements look wrong, as they are missing the final term. You use placeholders for the `location` and `root` values, so it's not obvious if you should be using `root` or `alias`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your comment. I checked some things (see update above) but the problem didn't go away

Comment: @RichardSmith I think I found the cause but honestly have no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx` chooses a one `location` to [process a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). Your `location ~* \.(?:eot|woff|woff2|ttf|js)$` block processes any URI that ends with `.js`, and its `root` value is inherited from the outer block as `/var/opt/data/web`.

Where you have multiple roots, you need to ensure that those `location` blocks take precedence, by using the `^~` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/opt/data/web;
    ...    
    location ~* \.(?:eot|woff|woff2|ttf|js)$ {
        expires 1M;
    }    
    ...
    location ^~ /one {
        root /var/opt/data/alternatives;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        location ~* \.(?:eot|woff|woff2|ttf|js)$ {
            expires 1M;
        }    
    }
    ...
}
```

If you need your `expires` rule to apply to the other roots, you will need to repeat the `location` within that scope, as shown above.

---

As an alternative, the `expires` directive can be used in conjunction with a `map`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) for details.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $expires {
    default                            off;
    ~*\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|js)(\?|$)  1M;
}
server {
    ...
    root /var/opt/data/web;
    expires $expires;
    ...
    location ^~ /one {
        root /var/opt/data/alternatives;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, up till today I didn't know that locations can be nested.